# How to obtain the number (count) of new indexes affected when a new column is considered

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have the next problem to solve.

i hava a huge dataframe (14 k rows x 1600 columns) consisting of 1 and 0s. I need to obtain the unique new different values when i considered a new column. Meaning, i have the index column and the first column, then if i consider the second column, i need to be able to obtain the 'count' of how many of the rows are different to the first column. Then, consider the third column and obtain the count of the different values to those from 1st and 2nd column and so on. for example the following dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["S1", "S2", "S3"])
df
```

(1 is present, 0 is absence, this means, in column1, the index(0) was 'observed', in colum2 is '0', meaning it was not observed, and so on).

because i'm not sure how to write the code, i don't know if is easier to get a new row at the end with the count of the new values or transpose the df and obtain a new column with those values. in any case the output i expect should be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [[1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 1], [3, 1, 1]]
df_out = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["S1", "S2", "S3"])
df_out
```

Here you can see that with just column 1 there are 3 unique index-value pairs, when we considered columns 1 and 2, we have 2 repeated values but 1 new, and when we add the third column we have just 1 new value when compared with 1 and 2...

So, to clarify myself, look the image below. enter image description here
[image]

for this example, i need to count the total of '1' present in column1, then, when i considered column2 i need the count of cases [0,1], when i considered a third column i need the count of the cases [0,0,1], for a fourth column the cases [0,0,0,1] and so on.

[In this link you can download a small section of the original DF with the total unique '1' at the end (obtained manually)](https://www.dropbox.com/t/uWRDF5jOcQdzkjfJ)

I need to obtain that kind of output for the entire dataframe.

Hope someone can help.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Within a row, `1` can become `0`. Can it become `1` again? Then how should it be considered? New again or not? For instance let's assume row 1 is `[1,0,1]`

Comment: Sorry, i think i did not express myself correctly (i updated the question). This is a table of observed/notobserved, meaning: for the index(0) in column1 there is a '1' cause it was observed, in column2 there is a '0' cause it was not observed, and in the column3 a '1' cause it was observed. The idea would be to say, ah ok, the index(0) was observed in column1 for the first time, when i check column3, it is present but it has been already recorded in column1, so i ignore it. I want to for example in column3 all the cases type [0,0,1], for column4 only the cases [0,0,0,1] and so on.

Comment: I am sorry but your question is still ambiguous. What would be the expected result (last row only) for this input: `import itertools ; pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(*[[0,1]]*3), columns=['S1','S2','S3'])`

Comment: for that case i would expect this: [4,2,1]. S1 is the starting point with four '1' (index 4 to 7), then when i considered just S1&S2, it presents 2 new '1' not present in S1 before (index 2 &3). then, when i consider S1&S2&S3 the answer is 1, cause only the index 1 is new, the other '1' present in S3 are presen in S2 and/or S1 (case of S3 index3 (present in S2), index5 (present in S1) and index7 (present in S2 and S1)).

Comment: OK, i got it I think, [see my edited answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68541393/16343464). If this still does not work, then please craft a new minimal example (5/6 rows max) with the expected answer in a case where our answers do not work

Comment: hmm... i still get the (3,1,1) cause in that case when i consider S3, the '1' in the first row appeared first in the S1, so i do not count it for S3. I think what's difficult to explain maybe it that, i should start with S1 and count... then add the column 2 and considere just those 2 columns (S1 and S2) and count, then add S3 and count and so on

Comment: Actually it is quite simple, you do not need to think in terms of column, the rows are fully independent and you just need to find the first 1 per row. Have you tested the [updated answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68541393/16343464)?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use @Corralien's solution with a bit of pre-processing:

```
df[~df.sum(axis=1).eq(0)].idxmax(axis=1).value_counts()
```

or, alternatively

```
df.cumsum(axis=1).cumsum(axis=1).eq(1).sum()
```

---

##### old answer

You can compute the difference with the shifted dataframe and sum:

```
df2 = ((df-df.shift(axis=1)).eq(1))
df2['S1'] = df['S1']
df.append(df2.sum(), ignore_index=True)
```

output:

```
   S1  S2  S3
0   1   1   0
1   1   0   0
2   0   1   1
3   1   1   1
4   0   0   1
5   3   1   1
```

How it works:

```
>>> (df-df.shift(axis=1))
   S1   S2   S3
0 NaN  0.0 -1.0
1 NaN -1.0  0.0
2 NaN  1.0  0.0
3 NaN  0.0  0.0
4 NaN  0.0  1.0

>>> (df-df.shift(axis=1)).eq(1)
       S1     S2     S3
0  False  False  False
1  False  False  False
2  False   True  False
3  False  False  False
4  False  False   True

>>> df2['S1'] = df['S1']
   S1     S2     S3
0   1  False  False
1   1  False  False
2   0   True  False
3   1  False  False
4   0  False   True

>>> df2.sum()
S1    3
S2    1
S3    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation! super nice, but i don't get the right answer when i apply it to the real DF... i just updated the question with a link to download a section of the real data, if that can help. i included the correct answer at the bottom of the df. What i'm having when i apply the code above is total count of rows for the first columns, not exactly the count of the '1'.

Comment: Well, you have values like (1,0,1). What should happen in this case? (see my comment to the question)

Comment: Actually, can you rework your question with this DataFrame as example: `import itertools ; pd.DataFrame(itertools.product(*[[0,1]]*3), columns=['S1','S2','S3'])`

Comment: I just saw that you fixed the problem of idxmax! +1

Answer (score 1):

> for this example, i need to count the total of '1' present in column1, then, when i considered column2 i need the count of cases [0,1], when i considered a third column i need the count of the cases [0,0,1], for a fourth column the cases [0,0,0,1] and so on.

In fact, you want to count where '1' appears for the first time:

```
>>> df[~df.eq(0).all(axis=1)].idxmax(axis=1).value_counts()
S1    151
S2    148
S3    113
dtype: int64
```

```
>>> df.append(df[~df.eq(0).all(axis=1)].idxmax(axis=1).value_counts(), ignore_index=True)
        S1   S2   S3
0        1    1    1
1        0    0    0
2        0    0    0
3        0    0    0
4        0    0    0
...    ...  ...  ...
14338    0    0    0
14339    0    0    0
14340    0    0    0
14341    0    0    0
14342  151  148  113

[14343 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Nice way to do it ;) +1 Our solutions would behave differently if the values can shift many times. I asked OP for clarification

Comment: This is an interesting proposition, but i don't get the right answer when i apply it to the real DF... i just updated the question with a link to download a section of the real data, if that can help. i included the correct answer at the bottom of the df. What i'm having when i apply the code above is total count of rows for the first columns, not exactly the count of the '1'.

Comment: @Corralien, in fact is not when '1' appears for the first time, is to record for how many time a '1' appears when a new column is added, meaning, how many new '1' are in the second column not registered in the first.. same, when i add a N column, how many new '1' does it contains not present in the previous columns...

Comment: @Corralien in addition to OP's new issue, you need to drop rows with zeros only or else they will be counted…

Comment: @LuisManuelQuirosguerrero, I updated my answer to avoid the bug of the first column because idxmax return 0 for all rows that contain only 0.

Comment: @Corralien, thanks! i'm testing it already